# How to change a cell depending on content in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a lot of cells that contain some numbers and other non-relevant characters. For example cell may look like: `65f` or as `11,345asd`.

My goal is to delete everything but numbers in these cells, so I could use these numbers for further calculations. I have found a lot of similar questions on different sites, but they are quite specific and I still don't understand how to do it properly.

So the question is how to use change cells or maybe even a range of cells depending on contents? I have some ideas how to do it using string function Replace. But nothing that looks good.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use this function by Matthews Patrick to remove non numeric characters from a cell http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=816

Comment: Another one http://www.vbusers.com/code/codeget.asp?ThreadID=624&PostID=1

Comment: I checked another answer not because I think it is better but because I can't understnad your answer. I am new to excel, VBA so Alex's answer is just what I was looking for, it is more suitable for me. If my actions violate rules of this site I can undo this. Still thanks for your answer and comments. I understood examples in both comments and I will return to your example when I am more educated in VBA.

Comment: No you have not violated any rules :) Also there is no need to now unaccept Alex's answer. :) `but because I can't understnad your answer.` Strange that you say this because I have explained with screenshots. But anyways lets leave it at that.

Comment: I don't mean that I can't use your answer. I can use it and it will work. In this way it is perfectly understandable. But I can't understnand how it is working in a way that I can modify or change something for another purpose.

Comment: Its not really looping through every character in a cell, its looping through every character in a string & will be several times faster than a regexp

Comment: @AlexK. I am afraid you are mistaken Alex. Here is a test file. http://wikisend.com/download/936170/Sample.xlsm There are 2 buttons. One for my macro and one for yours... Please test it yourself. My macro takes 7 seconds on 10k rows with each cell having a string of 5915 characters whereas your function takes 25 seconds :)

Comment: Your point is fair, however @ say 64 characters per cell the result is reversed with VBA performing twice as fast as an RE, the bigger you go  the more the character loop costs relative to the RE processing & com marshalling

Comment: True. In such a scenario where there are 64 chars in the string as compared to 5096 characters, the looping is greatly reduced and hence your code becomes faster. Like I mentioned earlier Regxp is faster than looping characters in the cell. What I probably should have added to the above statement is that `Regxp is faster than looping characters in the cell when the complexity of the search in the string and the length of the string increases` as you rightly mentioned that `the bigger you go the more the character loop costs` and that is my point as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A wee function

```
public function TONUM(str As string) As string
dim i As long
for i = 1 To len(str)
    if not mid$(str, i, 1) Like "[0-9]" then mid$(str, i, 1) = "?"
next
TONUM = replace$(str, "?", "")
end function
```

Answer (score 9):

Another way using RegExp

**Adding Reference**

Add a reference to *Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5*. See image below

[image]

**CODE:** Paste this in a module

```
Option Explicit

Function GetNumbers(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim StrSample As String
    Dim myRegExp As RegExp
    Dim myMatches As MatchCollection
    Dim myMatch As Match

    StrSample = rng.Value

    Set myRegExp = New RegExp

    With myRegExp
        .Pattern = "[^0-9]"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
    End With

    Set myMatches = myRegExp.Execute(StrSample)

    For Each myMatch In myMatches
      Debug.Print myMatch.Value
      StrSample = Replace(StrSample, myMatch.Value, "")
    Next
    GetNumbers = StrSample
End Function
```

**SCREENSHOT**:

[image]

**EDIT**

Here is a shorter version which doesn't use looping at all.

```
Function GetNumbers(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim myRegExp As RegExp
    Set myRegExp = New RegExp
    myRegExp.Pattern = "[^0-9]"
    myRegExp.Global = True
    GetNumbers = myRegExp.Replace(rng.Value, "")
End Function
```

Comment: +1 RegEx is definitely faster in such cases... especially your edited function.